# Why does this not output 'Junk'?

Tags: c

So I have this union call Junk. it holds an int, or a char[4] array... You can probably tell what I am trying to do. I put the ASCII values of the letters J, u, n, and k into my int, with the J going into the first byte, u in the second, etc. I do this because my machine is little endian, and I expect the byte containing J to be the leftmost byte in my int, which should correspond with numc[0]. But I don't get any output. So what is going wrong?

```
#include <stdio.h>

union Junk {
  int num;
  char numc[4];
};

int
main(int argc, char ** argv){
  union Junk len;
  len.num = 74;         //J
  len.num &= 117 << 8;  //u
  len.num &= 110 << 16; //n
  len.num &= 107 << 24; //k
  putchar(len.numc[0]);
  putchar(len.numc[1]);
  putchar(len.numc[2]);
  putchar(len.numc[3]);
  putchar('\n');
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Note that this is technically undefined behavior. You're trying to read the value of `numc` without setting it. The standard says that reading from any element in a union other than the last one that was modified is undefined behavior. Of course, it does usually work in practice if you do it right.

Comment: You might want to use `|=` instead of `&=`.

Comment: @CodyGray: That's not true. _If the member used to read the contents of a union object is not the same as the member last used to store a value in the object, the appropriate part of the object representation of the value is reinterpreted as an object representation in the new type as described in 6.2.6 (a process sometimes called ‘‘type punning’’). This might be a trap representation._ This is footnote 95 in C 2011.

Comment: You know you are depending on little-endian format?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You use `&=` instead of `|=` to set the bits. Because the operands of `&` have no overlapping bits, you are just setting your `len` number to zero.

Comment: god dammit! haha, I knew I must have been making some dumb mistake. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

You need to OR the bytes, not AND them.  Here's a working version: http://rextester.com/MPS15691